# Header only library doesn't use header guards. How can I use the library in other header files?

Tags: c

I'm working with a header only library ([Nuklear](https://github.com/vurtun/nuklear/)). I include this in my `main.c` file like so:

```
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_opengl.h>

#define NK_INCLUDE_FIXED_TYPES
#define NK_INCLUDE_STANDARD_IO
#define NK_INCLUDE_STANDARD_VARARGS
#define NK_INCLUDE_DEFAULT_ALLOCATOR
#define NK_INCLUDE_VERTEX_BUFFER_OUTPUT
#define NK_INCLUDE_FONT_BAKING
#define NK_INCLUDE_DEFAULT_FONT
#define NK_IMPLEMENTATION
#define NK_SDL_GL3_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "nuklear.h"
#include "nuklear_sdl_gl3.h"
```

I want to create a file to house some components and break the code up into smaller chunks. I tried to do this by including `nuklear.h` into one of the component headers but got a re declaration error:

```
error: redefinition of 'nk_sdl_shutdown'
```

I don't know any other way to access the types from `nuklear.h` in other header files. Any help please?

Comment: Please post full error messages. I believe this is no a full code. Show the rest of `main.c` file and the smallest reproducible sample files with command line, compiler invokation and compiler options needed to reproduce the issue. Well, on top of the head, did you include `nuklear_sdl_gl3` twice? What if you change the order of includes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [it does include header guards](https://github.com/vurtun/nuklear/blob/master/nuklear.h#L220) now.  Try updating the library.  If that doesn't work file a bug or, even better, a pull request.

It's open source software, if you find something wrong you can fix it instead of trying to work around the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the `#include` for that library in another header.

```c
#ifndef NUKLEAR_INCLUDED
#define NUKLEAR_INCLUDED

#define NK_INCLUDE_FIXED_TYPES
#define NK_INCLUDE_STANDARD_IO
#define NK_INCLUDE_STANDARD_VARARGS
#define NK_INCLUDE_DEFAULT_ALLOCATOR
#define NK_INCLUDE_VERTEX_BUFFER_OUTPUT
#define NK_INCLUDE_FONT_BAKING
#define NK_INCLUDE_DEFAULT_FONT
#define NK_IMPLEMENTATION
#define NK_SDL_GL3_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "nuklear.h"
#include "nuklear_sdl_gl3.h"

#endif
```